# Why creating an URL object (with wrong URL) takes a long time in Java?

Tags: java

EDIT: it turned out this question had been asked the wrong way — see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8942700/838434). Please vote to close it.

For a unit test, I need to make the `new java.net.URL(String)` constructor throw a `MalformedURLException`, but it takes an awfully long time for what it does — 2.5 seconds.

I understand this is probably related to an attempt to create a protocol handler, so I tried specifying no protocol handler, e.g.:

```
new URL(null);
new URL("://");
new URL("/abc");
```

I briefly looked through the implementation, it seems to be preparsing the URL string to eliminate obvious errors. Why does it take so long, even with "null"?

Comment: The question is : How do you mesure the times it takes ? On my little machine, in a GroovyConsole (much much slower than a pure java program), I create a URL in 150~200 ms, even with a MalformedURLException. Which version of the JVM do you use ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  On my system, `new URL(null)` throws and catches in less than 1ms.

Comment: I have tried all 3 variants of these URLs on my Mac running on java version "1.6.0_29". It consistently took 0 or 1 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be something else causing the delay?  I can't reproduce this:

```
public class UrlTest {

    static public void urltest(String s) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            new URL(s);
            System.out.println("successfully created URL after "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+" milliseconds. URL: "+s);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString()+" after "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+" milliseconds. URL: "+s);         
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        urltest(null);
        urltest("://");
        urltest("/abc");

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.6.0_18-ea
java.net.MalformedURLException after 0 milliseconds. URL: null
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: :// after 1 milliseconds. URL: ://
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /abc after 0 milliseconds. URL: /abc
```

Regarding `equals()`, this is from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Two hosts are considered equivalent if both host names can be resolved into the same IP addresses; else if either host name can't be resolved, the host names must be equal without regard to case; or both host names equal to null.
>
> Since hosts comparison requires name resolution, this operation is a blocking operation.
>
> Note: The defined behavior for equals is known to be inconsistent with virtual hosting in HTTP.

Comment: Thanks. I've added my answer with explanation.

Comment: Note that not only `equals()`, but also `hashCode()` does DNS resolution. I.e. even putting a single URL into a hash set (or map key) is problematic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987629/add-to-hashmap-takes-a-long-time.

Answer (score 3):

Because the URL class goes quite some length and tries several different attempts to resolve the given (illegal) Url. It even tries to load different system packages which are resolved using the Urls contents.

The exact procedure is laid out in the Javadoc of the [URL constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29).

Since these actions involve accessing and loading different classes and files, the first access to such illegal Urls can take quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for sharing your unit test results — you were right, the URL creation takes next to nothing. The comparison causes the trouble:

```
Assert.assertThat(url, equalTo(new URL("http://aa"))); // about 2 seconds
```

It seems like **there's REALLY a call to `http://aa`**! It seems that only with "localhost" it is fast:

```
Assert.assertThat(url, equalTo(new URL("http://localhost"))); // a few ms
```

The solution would be to compare the String representation:

```
Assert.assertThat(url.toExternalForm(), equalTo(new URL("http://aa").toExternalForm()));
```

Comment: URL.equals() uses 2.5 seconds in my test as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use URI to improve perfomance?

> Note, the URI class does perform escaping of its component fields in
> certain circumstances. The recommended way to manage the encoding and
> decoding of URLs is to use URI, and to convert between these two
> classes using toURI() and URI.toURL().
>
> The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for
> HTML form encoding, which is not the same as the encoding scheme
> defined in RFC2396.

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

> “People are encouraged to use URI for parsing and URI comparison, and
> leave URL class for accessing the URI itself, getting at the protocol
> handler, interacting with the protocol etc. So, at present, we don’t
> plan on changing the URL.equals/hashCode behavior and we will leave
> the bug open until Tiger, when we re-investigate our options.”

From https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4434494 , 2001.

Answer (score 0):

Single step through it and see where it spends its time!

I expect it's trying to do a DNS lookup and your DNS client or server are misconfigured.

Comment: The point is: there really isn't anything to look up in these URLs!

Comment: Indeed, which is why I'm suspicious that it's trying anyway and a DNS misconfiguration is causing a timeout wait.