# Add to hashmap takes a long time

Tags: java

I've stuck by a few lines in my java program, which take too much time (about 20s), and it seems weird to me.

Here are the lines

```
 Map<URL, Integer> res2 = new HashMap<>();
 for (URL url : res) {
     res2.put(url, null);
 }
```

Which res defined as following :

```
List<URL> res = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my program, res.size() ~= 1500

Do you have any idea of where my problem could come from ?

Thanks !

Comment: try sizing your hashmap appropriately. new HashMap(1500);

Comment: Why do you need a map when you are inserting null values against each key ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `hashCode()` method of `java.net.URL` performs DNS resolution. The `URL` class is unsuitable for use in a `HashSet` or as keys in a `HashMap`. Use either Strings or `java.net.URI`.

Here's some background:

- [Michael Scharf:  java.net.URL.equals and hashCode make (blocking) Internet connections....](http://michaelscharf.blogspot.com/2006/11/javaneturlequals-and-hashcode-make.html)
- [Eishay Smith: Java's URL little secret](http://www.eishay.com/2008/04/javas-url-little-secret.html) (which RobAu linked in a comment to this answer)